# Annual sales change

Tags: postgresql

my query so far using joins: quantity - number of goods purchased, date - date of transaction, name - customer_name, year - year of transaction. Similar to the daily change, I tried using an annual difference and pass in the query to satisfy the conditions.

```
SELECT s1.year, s1.name, sum(s1.quantity)
FROM T1 s1
JOIN T2 s2
ON s1.date::timestamp - s2.date::timestamp = '1 year'
WHERE (s1.quantity > s2.quantity AND s1.year BETWEEN 2015 and 2017)
OR (s1.quantity < s2.quantity AND s1.year BETWEEN 2018 and 2019)
GROUP BY 1,2
```

Comment: Please tag the appropriate database.  Also sample data desired results would be helpful.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti, I have added the sample data now.

Comment: What do rows in that table represent? Are they already summarized for that year?

Comment: quantity - number of goods purchased that day 
name - customer name
date - date of the purchase 
year - year extracted from the date (basically the year in which the purchase happened)
Please note: This is a made up table that I created to solve this question. The query should return customer name as "Sajith".

Comment: And you mean increased from both 2017 over 2016 and 2016 over 2015 and then decreased from 2018 to 2019?

Comment: That's correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with data as (
    SELECT name,
        COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN year = 2015 THEN qty ELSE 0 END), 0) AS total2015,
        COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN year = 2016 THEN qty ELSE 0 END), 0) AS total2016,
        COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN year = 2017 THEN qty ELSE 0 END), 0) AS total2017,
        COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN year = 2018 THEN qty ELSE 0 END), 0) AS total2018,
        COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN year = 2019 THEN qty ELSE 0 END), 0) AS total2019
    FROM sajith_gowthaman.practice_annual_inc1
    WHERE year BETWEEN 2015 and 2019
    GROUP BY name
)
select *
from data
where   total2015 < total2016
    and total2016 < total2017
    and total2018 > total2019;
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much :)